# AngularJS mouse event is fired multiple times in a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to trigger the function `setHighlight` when a `li` element is hovered by mouse. The `ng-mouseover` event is set in an `ng-repeat` loop.

The issue is that when I hover a `li` element, the `ng-mouseover` is triggered multiple time. The number of trigger times equals to the number of iteration times. Here is my code snippet:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="review in foodReviews" ng-mouseover="setHighlight(review.id)">
        <h4>{{review.name}}</h4>
        <b>{{review.stars}} Stars</b>
        <i> -- {{review.location}} </i><br />
        <blockquote> {{review.description}} </blockquote>
        <br/> written by {{review.author}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Did I put the hover event in a wrong place?

Comment: Im not that familiar with angular but yeah its looks  like the mouseover is in the loop

Comment: mouseover event bubbles up but mouseenter does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mouseover event happens any time the element or any of it's children are hovered over. Therefore, whenever you hover over the h4 inside the li, another mouseover event is triggered. You should instead use the mouseenter event.

```
ng-mouseenter="setHighlight(review.id)"
```

Comment: As far as your claim: *"The number of trigger times equals to the number of iteration times"* i think that was a false positive.